# printing the ranges of fundamental datatypes in c

Tags: c

I was trying the solve the problem of printing the ranges of fundamental datatypes in C.

but I see that the values are wrong. Can anyone please point out my error ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<float.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp=fopen("/*path to the file*/","w");
    fprintf(fp,"Printing the ranges for data types:\n");
    fprintf(fp,"Type    Min_Value    Max_Value    Range\n");
    fprintf(fp,"*************************************************************************************************************************************************\n");
    fprintf(fp,"char    %4d     %4d%4d\n\n",CHAR_MIN,CHAR_MAX,CHAR_MAX-CHAR_MIN);
    fprintf(fp,"uchar     0     %4d    %4d\n\n",UCHAR_MAX,UCHAR_MAX);
    fprintf(fp,"schar     %d     %4d    %4d\n\n",SCHAR_MIN,SCHAR_MAX,SCHAR_MAX-SCHAR_MIN);
    fprintf(fp,"int    %li    %li    %lu\n\n",(INT_MIN,INT_MAX,INT_MAX-INT_MIN));
    fprintf(fp,"uint    %d    %lu    %u\n\n",0,UINT_MAX,UINT_MAX);
    fprintf(fp,"long    %lli    %llu    %llu\n\n",LONG_MIN,LONG_MAX,LONG_MAX-LONG_MIN);
    fprintf(fp,"ulong    %ll    %ll    %lu\n\n",0,ULONG_MAX,ULONG_MAX);
    fprintf(fp,"short    %ll    %ll    %ld\n\n",SHRT_MIN,SHRT_MAX,SHRT_MAX-SHRT_MIN);
    fprintf(fp,"ushort    %ld    %ll    %ld\n\n",0,USHRT_MAX,USHRT_MAX);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

this is the output

```
Printing the ranges for data types:
Type                Min_Value               Max_Value               Range
*************************************************************************************************************************************************
char                 -128                127                 255

uchar                0               255                 255

schar                -128                127                 255

int             -1              127             255

uint                0               4294967295              4294967295

long                9223372034707292160             18047113275375615               18047512710020968

ulong                                               0

short                                               -32768

ushort              0                               65535
```

after updating the code and using the format specifiers the values for int and unsigned int and long are wrong here is the update.

```
printf("int      %15d    %15d    %15u\n\n",INT_MIN,INT_MAX,INT_MAX-INT_MIN);
        printf("uint      %u     %15u    %15u\n\n",0,UINT_MAX,UINT_MAX);
        printf("long      %15l   %15l    %15lu\n\n",LONG_MIN,LONG_MAX,LONG_MAX-LONG_MIN);
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by the line "values are messed up"? are you worried about the layout of the output?

Comment: sorry.i mean values are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

Use `d` for signed integers.

Use `u` for unsigned integers.

`char` and `short` are promoted to `int`. Don't add `ll` or `l` to them.

Add `l` with `long` types, not `ll`.

**Edit:**

To clarify:

```
int == %d
unsigned int == %u
long == %ld
unsigned long == %lu
```

Also you cannot represent range of signed integer with the same data type, you need to use bigger type. `INT_MAX-INT_MIN` won't work. It needs to be `(long)INT_MAX-(long)INT_MIN` and you need to use `%ld` to display it. And even that won't work if `sizeof int == sizeof long`.

Comment: but what if i subtract long_min from long_max.that would cause an overflow for long's right?

Comment: @programer8 Well, yes. But not with the values you got in your output.

Comment: i dint really get you.i modified the program but the values from int uint and long are wrong

Comment: @programer8 Please add the latest code that doesn't work AND the output to your question. We can't quess what is wrong and what changes you made.

Comment: int shud have a range of +/-32767 and uint shud have a range of 0-65535

Comment: No. C standard says that int range must be **at least** +/-32767. It might be bigger, it depends on the compiler. In your enviroment `int` is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`man 3 printf` (or [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)) will give you the format codes for all integer types.  You'll see that you're using the wrong ones for most of your results, e.g. you're using `"%li"` for an `int`, instead of `"%d"`.  Also, the result of substracting the minimum value from the maximum value is generally not representable in the same integer data type and needs casting.

Comment: hey i wasn't talking about the formatting. but that helps though. i was saying that the values are wrong and can you please point out where i was subtracting smaller number from a larger one?

Comment: I'm not talking about the formatting either! You can't print an integer with the long integer format code. You'll see a different value! And I didn't say your subtracting is wrong, but that the result is not representable with this type.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
fprintf(fp,"int    %li    %li    %lu\n\n",(INT_MIN,INT_MAX,INT_MAX-INT_MIN));
```

to:

```
fprintf(fp,"int    %li    %li    %lu\n\n", INT_MIN,INT_MAX,INT_MAX-INT_MIN);
```

Funny bug. Your compiler should have caught it and given you warning that the number of arguments to `printf` is wrong. Do you compile with warning enabled? If not, you should. And definitely not ignore the warnings.

Comment: i get the values int   -1   127 255 and uint gave me a max value of 4294967295 and float wont display the min value